# Using screen mix-blend-mode to get white when combining red green and blue divs

Tags: html, css, mix-blend-mode

I am using the `screen` value of `mix-blend-mode` to combine three divs, one of each of red green and blue. I think I should expect white at the center of the combined divs, but the colours seem off. Am i misunderstanding how this works, or am I using it incorrectly? Thank you.

See this code snippet:

```css
body {
  background-color: black;
}

.shape {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  border-radius: 150px;
  mix-blend-mode: screen;
  position: absolute;
}

#red {
  background-color: red;
  left: 75px;
}

#green {
  background-color: green;
  top: 125px;
}

#blue {
  background-color: blue;
  top: 125px;
  left: 150px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="shape" id="blue"></div>
  <div class="shape" id="red"></div>
  <div class="shape" id="green"></div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're doing it right.
The thing is that the css `red, blue, green` are not pure red, pure blue and pure green and can be interpreted by the browser your are using.

Instead, you should use :

```
#FF0000;
#00FF00;
#0000FF;
```

```css
body {
  background-color: black;
}

.shape {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  border-radius: 150px;
  mix-blend-mode: screen;
  position: absolute;
}

#red {
  background-color: #FF0000;
  left: 75px;
}

#green {
  background-color: #00FF00;
  top: 125px;
}

#blue {
  background-color: #0000FF;
  top: 125px;
  left: 150px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="shape" id="blue"></div>
  <div class="shape" id="red"></div>
  <div class="shape" id="green"></div>
</body>
```